# Create custom objects on the fly

Tags: java, object

I would like to know if there's a way to create objects on the fly or should I say by not using a Class object and its properties. The normal way I'm doing it is this.

```
ApiHelper apiHelper = new ApiHelper();
User user = new User();
user.Firstname = "FirstName";
apiHelper.send("", user);
```

I would like to accomplish this on my code snippet:

```
ApiHelper apiHelper = new ApiHelper();
apiHelper.send("", new { Firstname = "Firstname"});
```

The second paramter on send() has a data type of Object and this Object is later on converted to json string.

This is a c# example, is there a counterpart of this in java? I kind of think that if I use the first approach when creating objects, I have to a lot of classes just to comply with the objects that I need to build, So I was hoping to if I can do it in java using the 2nd approach.

Comment: a simple use case in Java is to to return multiple values from a method. In JavaScript it is easy: you do return { your new object here}, but in Java it's not that easy. I see a use for it. The ultimate reason why it's not easy in Java is that you can't dynamically change members or accessors at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, that's possible with Java. the syntax would be this:

```
apiHelper.send("", new Object(){ String firstName = "Firstname"});
```

However, that's generally pretty useless. What you more likely want to do it create an interface/class to define the methods and fields you want, and pass an instance of that.

Example:

```
class Data{
    String firstname;
    public Data(String firstname){
        this.firstname=firstname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how using that syntax is useless? Well, you answered my question and that's what I've been looking for so I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ljpv14 It's generally useless because there's not a practical way to access that value later. It should be possible with reflection, but usually you want a more direct way to extract the data from the object.

Comment: Well, I didn't clear it out that I will be using that object to send data to a webservice. Not really to create and save/process afterwards. So I think this approach is just about right.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all you really need is a constructor that takes the `Firstname` as a parameter.

```
public User(String fName) {
    Firstname = fName;
}
```

Although, capitalizing your members isn't convention in Java as it is in C#; should be

`String firstname;`

Then you would just do...

`apiHelper.send("", new User("Firstname"));`

Comment: I figured I really have to do this but I say I would make this as my last option. Follow up question though, as you said, in java capitalizing my members isn't the convention. In my case, I'm converting this obj to json string and sending it on a webservice written in c#. And on that end, the properties/members are written with capitalization, will that create conflict?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I can't really see why it would.

Comment: @ljpv14, why would this be your last option; so are you saying you'll have to do this? After your clarification, and assuming that means you don't need to access the `User` after creating and passing it, why wouldn't the other answer(s) work?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify `User` to add a constructor, what I would use is "double brace initialization," where you can basically run code in a class where that class is instantiated:

```
ApiHelper apiHelper = new ApiHelper();
apiHelper.send("", new User(){{
        Firstname = "Firstname";
    }});
```

Then the line `Firstname = "Firstname";` gets executed immediately after instantiation.